# WP8 keyboard handling

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

How to handle page completely going up when clicking on the text box in WP8. (During the time of focus goes to textbox) and Keyboard renders.I want to block header(page frame) going out of screen.

Answer (score 4):

This is a known issue.

You can use something like that https://siphelper.codeplex.com/.

Or write you own code ([based on this page](http://sorokoletov.com/2011/08/windows-phone-70-handling-text-entry-screens/)) to put the layout down when keyboard is appearing.

```
When SIP keyboard is rendered, PhoneApplicationFrame.TranslateTransform.Y 
is set to specific values (-259 in landscape orientation, -339 in portrait orientation). 
To update layout, we’ll just set top margin to the specified value(-s) and 
after that Silverlight layout system will fix the issue.
```

However, this is a common behavior for the platform. Users are familiar with it.